# Why do we get SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON while using elastic-apm-node?

Tags: node.js, express, elastic-apm

After adding elastic-apm-node on our backend server we receive the below error hundreds of times a day. Can anyone suggest what might cause this?

The error we see is this:

```
     { SyntaxError: Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:158:10)
    at parse (/usr/src/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
    at done (/usr/src/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/usr/src/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.elasticAPMCallbackWrapper (/usr/src/app/node_modules/elastic-apm-node/lib/instrumentation/index.js:309:27)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  expose: true,
  statusCode: 400,
  status: 400,
  body:
   '"<html>\\r\\n<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>\\r\\n<body bgcolor=\\"white\\">\\r\\n<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>\\r\\n</body>\\r\\n</html>\\r\\n"',
  type: 'entity.parse.failed',
  traceId: 'ERR-344BC630',
  [Symbol(ElasticAPMErrorReported)]: true }
```

I think we run node v10.x but I'm not absolutely sure.

The service is built on feathersJS which again is built on Express.

We start APM like this:

```
require("elastic-apm-node").start({
    serviceName: "serviceX",
    serverUrl: "http://xxx:8200"
});
```

The dependencies listed in package.json are:

```
"dependencies": {
        "@sendgrid/mail": "^6.0.0",
        "advisory-lock": "^1.1.1",
        "aws-sdk": "^2.265.1",
        "axios": "^0.19.0",
        "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
        "check-types": "^7.3.0",
        "compression": "^1.7.2",
        "config": "^1.26.2",
        "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.3.0",
        "cors": "^2.8.4",
        "cron": "^1.3.0",
        "elastic-apm-node": "^3.2.0",
        "elasticsearch": "^16.5.0",
        "feathers": "^2.2.4",
        "feathers-authentication": "^1.3.1",
        "feathers-authentication-hooks": "^0.3.0",
        "feathers-authentication-jwt": "^0.3.2",
        "feathers-authentication-local": "^0.4.4",
        "feathers-configuration": "^0.4.1",
        "feathers-errors": "^2.9.1",
        "feathers-hooks": "^2.0.2",
        "feathers-hooks-common": "^3.7.1",
        "feathers-rest": "^1.8.1",
        "feathers-sequelize": "^2.3.0",
        "feathers-socketio": "^2.0.1",
        "gm": "^1.23.1",
        "heapdump": "^0.3.15",
        "helmet": "^3.20.0",
        "i18n": "^0.8.3",
        "jws": "^3.1.5",
        "lodash": "^4.17.15",
        "logstash-client": "^1.1.1",
        "moment": "^2.22.2",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.23",
        "multer": "^1.3.0",
        "mustache": "^2.3.0",
        "node-rdkafka": "^2.7.1-2",
        "node-uuid": "^1.4.8",
        "passport-saml": "^0.33.0",
        "pg": "^6.4.2",
        "prom-client": "^11.2.1",
        "redis": "^2.8.0",
        "sequelize": "^4.38.0",
        "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0",
        "util": "^0.10.3",
        "uuid": "^3.1.0",
        "winston": "^2.3.1"
    },
```

Comment: `502 Bad Gateway` this is exactly error you get.